# How to check whether a list is a subset of another list

Tags: java, linked-list, subset

```
list1:[1,2,3,4,5]
list2:[1,2,3]
```

How to check if list2 is a subset of list1? I tried containsAll() but it gives true as long as the elements in list 2 are present in list1.
I want the same order as criteria and not just the elements.

Comment: What have you got so far? Where exactly do you have problems? Show us some code so we can help you.

Comment: @Turing85: I think OP just wants a ready made method from the API - doing it by hand should be, in fact, trivial.

Comment: What do you mean by order, a valid subset can be `[1, 3, 5]`?

Comment: You mean `[1, 3, 2]` should return `false`? What will `list2: [1, 3]` return? Can you make sure no duplicate elements in `list1` and `list2`, that means, `list1: [1, 3, 3, 4]` is invalid?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#indexOfSubList%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29

Comment: @coderz
Yes [1,3,2] should return false and should return true only if its is [1,2,3] and no duplicates.
so [1,2,3] is correct and [1,3,2] & [1,3,3,4] is false

Comment: @Zaq Also for each input list, there are no duplicate elements, right?

Comment: @coderz yes no dublicates

Comment: @jbarrueta [1,3,5] should give false and only[1,2,3] should give true

Comment: @Zaq must they start with the same value? i.e. [2,3,4] is not valid?

Comment: replace **List** with **Set** ... end of ur problem

Comment: @jbarrueta yes thats not valid, 
only if the list 2 is [2,3,4]. and list 1 is[1,2,3,4,5].
It should return true if and only if list 1 contains the exact list 2 inside that means no repetition and exact sequence

Comment: @Zaq updated the code based on your comments, it's simpler, hope it helps.

Answer (score 13):

Use this:

```
boolean contains(List<?> list, List<?> sublist) {
    return Collections.indexOfSubList(list, sublist) != -1;
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#indexOfSubList(java.util.List,%20java.util.List)

Comment: for list1:[1,2,3,4,5]
list2:[1,3]
Collections.indexOfSubList will return -1, while I believe list2 is considered subset of list1

Comment: If you read the 1st line in javadoc for List it says: "An ordered collection (also known as a sequence)." list2 is also a list which means it is a sequence and the sequence of the elements must be kept during the search. What you probably need is a  list.containsAll(sublist) but than sublist is just a collection as argument and not a sequence and element order is not important any more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Algorithm

1) Iterate over second list

2) Check if element is contained in first list

if no return false

If yes, get the index of that element from first list using [indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object))

3) Now while iterating check if next element is equal to list1(lastMatchedIndexFromList1++)

if  return false

if yes repeat step 3 and return true at end of iteration

Answer (score 1):

Iterate `list2` to check whether each element exists in `list1`. The most simple way is to use [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) to do check operation, it returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. Each check operation time complexity is `O(n)` because it has to iterate the whole list in worst case.

While if the `list1` is ordered, we can use [BinarySearch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to improve check operation performance to `O(lgn)` time complexity.

Sample code here:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 5));

boolean contains = true;
int l2 = list2.size();
int currIndex = -1;
for(int j=0;j<l2;j++) {
    int e2 = list2.get(j);
    int i1 = list1.indexOf(e2);
    if(i1 == -1) {
        contains = false;
        break;
    }
    if(i1 > currIndex) {
        currIndex = i1;
    }
}
System.out.println(contains);
```

The time complexity is `O(n * m)`, which `n` is `list1`'s size and `m` is `list2`'s size.

But, the most efficient way is not to use [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) method to do check. Since the occurence order is required, there is no need to iterate whole `list1` in each check operation. Just from last check point index to do checking!

Sample code here:

```
boolean contains = true;
int l1 = list1.size(), l2 = list2.size();
int currIndex = 0;
int i;
for(int j=0;j<l2;j++) {
    int e2 = list2.get(j);
    for(i=currIndex;i<l1;i++) {
        if(e2 == list1.get(i)) {
           break;
        }
    }
    if(i == l1) {
        contains = false;
        break;
    }
    currIndex++;
}
System.out.println(contains);
```

Both `list1` and `list2` are iterated just once, the time complexity is `O(n + m)`.

Answer (score 0):

I got a little curious about the implementation of this so this is my solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(3);
    list1.add(4);
    list1.add(5);

    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    list2.add(1);
    list2.add(2);
    list2.add(3);


    boolean isOrderedSublist = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {

        if(list1.get(i) != (int) list2.get(i)) {
            isOrderedSublist = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Is ordered: " + isOrderedSublist);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code for finding the elements in the order

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class OrderArray {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    List listSource = new ArrayList();
    for(int i =1; i <=5; i++) {
        listSource.add(i);
    }
    List target = new ArrayList();
    target.add(2);
    target.add(3);
    boolean isMatched = true;
    int [] indexArray = new int[target.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i< target.size(); i ++) {
        indexArray[i] = listSource.indexOf(target.get(i));
        if ( i !=0 ) {
            if ((indexArray[i] - indexArray[i-1]) != 1) {
                isMatched = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("isMatched:"+isMatched);
  }
}
```